# Executing a command via ssh and does not get saved in bash history

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, command-history

When I execute a command through SSH from a computer to my Linux server it doesn't save in its bash history.

I have my .bash_profile set like this:

```
[USER@ /home/USER]2 $cat .bash_profile
# .bash_profile



# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
. ~/.bashrc
fi



# User specific environment and startup programs
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/bin



export PATH



# Will Give me ip of person logged in
WHOAMI=`who -m | cut -d '(' -f 2| cut -d ')' -f1`
# Will give me tty ID
MYTTY=`who -m | awk '{print $2;}' | cut -d '/' -f2`
DATE=`date +"%Y_%m_%d_%H%M%S"`
DAY=`date +"%Y_%m_%d"`
shopt -s histappend
mkdir -p $HOME/HISTORY/${WHOAMI}/${DAY}
printf "#`date '+%s'`\nll\n" > $HOME/HISTORY/${WHOAMI}/${DAY}/.HIST_${MYTTY}_${DATE}



export HISTTIMEFORMAT='%F %T '
export HISTFILESIZE=100
export HISTSIZE=100
# stores history file per terminal
export HISTFILE=$HOME/HISTORY/${WHOAMI}/${DAY}/.HIST_${MYTTY}_${DATE}
export PS1='[\[\e[4;32m\]\u@\h\[\e[0m\] \[\e[1;36m\]$PWD\[\e[0m\]]\! $'
# Updates the HISTFILE at real time i.e. when user presses enter
export PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a; history -c; history -r; ${PROMPT_COMMAND}"
history -r $HISTFILE
```

If I execute a command in my local terminal it works well and it gets saved in history.

What I have to do to get commands launched via SSH get saved in my local bash history?

Comment: History is normally only enabled in interactive shells.

Comment: `.bash_profile` is only executed in login shells.

Answer (score 0):

Type bash into terminal when you log on and see if that fixes it.

If it does type `echo $SHELL` and see what your default shell is.

If you are on Ubuntu server your going to see `/bin/sh` type `usermod --shell /bin/bash "username"`

Verify by echo $SHELL and then grep "username" /etc/passwd
Reload ssh with systemctl reload sshd and then systemctl restart sshd.

Now Reboot and you should have color and history.

Sometimes you have to edit `.bashrc` file to force color on the line that's commented. And make sure that `.profile` is referencing that on login which it should be by default..

Let me know if this works!

PS: if you at anytime typed `sudo nano .bash_profile` or created a `.bash_profile` type `ls -la` in your home directory if you delete that and the follow the `systemctl` reload reboot you should be good you don't want your `.profile` to not be referenced.